# How to import and use Bulma framework with SCSS but not export all it's contents to CSS

Tags: css, sass, bulma

I have been using Bulma CSS framework a lot on my recent web projects, it's amazing and makes my work easier and straightforward.

However I don't use most of it's features, just a few. I know I can import only the files I need and for example: If I only need the columns system I would create a SCSS file like this:

```
@import "bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
@import "bulma/sass/grid/columns.sass";
```

This will generate a huge CSS file and I won't need the most of it! I will only make use of it with the @extend keyword like this:

```
.my-column {
  @extend .column;
  ...
}
```

But the generated CSS file will be poluted with lines like these:

```
/* line 3, ../sass/bulma/sass/grid/columns.sass */
.column, .my-column {
  display: block;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}
/* line 9, ../sass/bulma/sass/grid/columns.sass */
.columns.is-mobile > .column.is-narrow, .columns.is-mobile > .is-narrow.my-column {
  flex: none;
}
/* line 11, ../sass/bulma/sass/grid/columns.sass */
.columns.is-mobile > .column.is-full, .columns.is-mobile > .is-full.my-column {
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
}
/* line 14, ../sass/bulma/sass/grid/columns.sass */
.columns.is-mobile > .column.is-three-quarters, .columns.is-mobile > .is-    three-quarters.my-column {
  flex: none;
  width: 75%;
}
```

The first block is what I want only. I will not use most of the generated classes in my HTML, only the my-column class.

What I'm looking for is for the pre-processor only include in the class that I declare (my-column) what is needed in this way:

```
.my-column {
  display: block;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}
```

I don't know if it's possible, maybe is not necessary because the Bulma framework is very lightweight. I just don't like to have so much stuff in the CSS file that's not necessary.

Maybe I just got this whole SCSS pre-processor thing wrong. But if I did not made myself clear in anyway please let me know in the comments.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You might want to look into Post-CSS-Processing. 
Check out [purifycss on Github](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss).

Comment: Looks like what I'm looking for, but I have to use another tool! Anyway, for small projects do you think is worth it?

Comment: Well, if you already use Webpack or something similar, I would say it's worth it. Once you have your post css setup, you just copy and paste it for every project. Especially in small projects you only use a small part of your framework, the rest is overhead. 
But yes, if you have to invest too much time in setting up a workflow, you might think twice.